# JSON data not sorting alphabetically through Ajax call to grails controller

Tags: jquery, json, grails

The purpose is to get the reasons based on the decisionId so made the ajax call to controller layer to get the results in alphabetical order. I am getting the reason values to view layer but not in alphabetical order.

### Here is my code in js file

```
var getOverrideReasons = function (decisionId) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            categoryId : decisionId
        },
        url : 'detentionAssessment/getOverrideReasons',
        success : function(data) {
            $('#reason').empty()
            $('#reason').append($('<option />', { value: "", text: '***Select*** ' } ))
            data.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.value > b.value;
            });
            var obj = data.sort()

            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                $('#reason').append($('<option />', { value: key, text: value } ));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

### and my controller method is:

```
def getOverrideReasons(){
    def map = [:]
    def category
    if(params.categoryId.equals("1094")) {
        category = CategoryValue.orderByDescription(240)?.list()
    }

    if(params.categoryId.equals("2528")) {
        category = CategoryValue.orderByDescription(239)?.list()
    }

    category.each {it -> map.putAt(it.value?.id, it.value?.description)}
    render map as JSON
}
```

Comment: The return of the sort is expected to return a number that is < 0 (previous value), 0 (equality), or > 0 (subsequent value).  Yours is returning a boolean.  Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Thanks Taplar for the response, but in my js file getting the error if I try to sort Uncaught TypeError: data.sort is not a function

Comment: Well `def map = [:]` would indicate that the response is going to be a map, not an array.

Comment: Yes I am rendering map as JSON but want to render as JSON array and not sure of how to do it. Can you help me in that? Thanks

Comment: So change the `def map = []` and push the elements to it.  You'll probably want to push maps to it, something of the form `[ key: it.value?.id, value: it.value?.description ]` and then your json can sort the elements by either of those keys

Comment: Thanks Taplar it works. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
def getOverrideReasons(){
    def results
    def category

    if(params.categoryId.equals("1094")) {
        category = CategoryValue.orderByDescription(240)?.list()
    } else if(params.categoryId.equals("2528")) {
        category = CategoryValue.orderByDescription(239)?.list()
    } else {
        category = []
    }

    //collect the element into an array
    results = category.collect { [ key: it.value?.id, value: it.value?.description ] }

    render results as JSON
}




var getOverrideReasons = function (decisionId) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            categoryId : decisionId
        },
        url : 'detentionAssessment/getOverrideReasons',
        success : function(data) {
            $('#reason').empty()
            $('#reason').append($('<option />', { value: "", text: '***Select*** ' } ))
            //sort sorts the array in place, no need for another variable
            data.sort(function(a, b) {
                //value from the groovy looks like it will be a string so we
                //need to string compare the values
                return a.value.localeCompare(b.value);
            });

            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                $('#reason').append($('<option />', { value: element.key, text: element.value } ));
            });
        }
    });
}
```